# How can I receive bytea data from PostgreSQL through Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: zend-framework, postgresql, zend-db-select

I wrote a website with Zend Framework + Postgres. In PostgreSQL there is this table:

```
create table images(
    id                      serial,
    title                   TEXT DEFAULT '',
    thumbnail               bytea NOT NULL,
    original                bytea NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Where I'm planning to store image data. 
But when I try to receive anything from the table (`select thumbnail from images where id = $id`):

```
$table = $mapper->getDbTable();
$select = $table->select();
$select->from($table,array('thumbnail'));
$select->where('id = ?',$id);

$res = $table->fetchRow($select);
die(print_r($res['thumbnail']));
```

I receive something like:

```
Resource id #12_
```

but not the containing data.

How could I (using `Zend_Db_Select`) receive this data, but not a Resource id #129?
Sorry for my bad english ...

Comment: Nop. The resource id is always different than id of the record

Answer (score 3):

if the problem remains, replace this line:

```
die(print_r($res['thumbnail']));
```

by this:

```
die(fpassthru($res['thumbnail']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stream = $res['thumbnail'];
@unlink($pathFile);
touch($pathFile);
while (($buffer = (fgets($stream, 8192))) !== false) {
    file_put_contents($pathFile, $buffer, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.